# Custom Size UIModalPresentationFormSheet returns to default size when keyboard shows

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit

I'm displaying a custom sized modal with `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` like so:

```
    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
```

I want this view controller to have a custom size which I'm setting in the viewWillAppear (it's a mixed Objc-Swift project):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.view.superview?.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 540, height: 350)
}
```

This issue is the view controller has a UITextField that when selected (and the keyboard shows) the modal resizes to the default form sheet size. Any suggestions on how to keep the view controller the custom size even when the keyboard shows?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.

I was able to resolve the issue by setting `navController.preferredContentSize` before presenting the view controller rather than modifying the frame from within viewWillAppear.